# overflow-x: visible - uncertain who gets the scrollbar

Tags: html

I am visualising a log file, retrieved from the server in pieces. Each piece gets a `<pre>` element. When the log content is wider than the `<pre>` element the **browser** window shows a horizontal scrollbar, which is ideal.

However, in a more complex scenario (Bootstrap is involved) when the content is wider than the `<pre>` element the scrollbar is appears on the `<pre>` element itself, which is not ideal (as there may be many of them, each with their own scrollbar).

Can anyone tell me how to ensure the scrollbar appears on the browser window in both circumstances?

Comment: None of the `pre`'s ancestors can have a set width, which e.g. Bootstrap uses. Furthermore, your question in its present state is too broad and will be closed as such  if you don't narrow it down, with amongst other a [mcve] ... which you should know by now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The issue is provoked when the bootstrap CSS was included. The causative changes to the `<pre>` CSS were ..

```
//
// Contain overflow in all browsers.
//

pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

... which does what it says on the tin, and setting `overflow: visible` for my class did the trick. Interestingly setting only `overflow-z` was not enough.